# MEAN stack file uploading app throwing unreadable property error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack

I am learning the MEAN stack and was trying to build a simple file upload app. However, I am continuously hitting errors and I may be heading into the wrong direction. My latest error is the following:

```
<h1>Cannot read property &#39;file&#39; of undefined</h1>
<h2></h2>
<pre>TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;file&#39; of undefined
    at \routes\index.js:34:27
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
    at \node_modules\express-jwt\lib\index.js:112:9
    at \node_modules\jsonwebtoken\index.js:98:18
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)</pre>
```

Here is my `index.ejs` file:

```
<form ng-submit="addPhoto()" ng-model="image" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="imageFile">File input</label>
  <input type="file" id="imageFile" ng-model="file">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
</form>
```

Code for `routes\index.js` file:

```
router.post('/photos', auth, function(req, res, next) {
  var dirname = require('path').dirname(__dirname);
  var filename = req.files.file.name;
  var path = req.files.file.path;
  var type = req.files.file.mimetype;

  var read_stream = fs.createReadStream(dirname + '/' + path);
  var conn = req.conn;
  var Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
  Grid.mongo = mongoose.mongo;
  var gfs = Grid(conn.db);

  var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({
    filename: filename
  });
  read_stream.pipe(writestream);

  photo.save(function(err, photo){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    res.json(photo);
  });
});
```

And here is the `angularApp.js` file:

```
app.factory('photos', ['$http', 'auth', function($http, auth){
  var o = { photos: [] };
  o.create = function(photo) {
    return $http.post('/photos', photo, {
      headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer '+auth.getToken()}
    }).success(function(data){
      o.photos.push(data);
    }).error(function(a) {
      console.log(a);
    });
  };
  return o;
}]);
app.controller('MainCtrl', [
'$scope',
'photos',
'auth',
function($scope, photos, auth){
  $scope.photos = photos.photos;
  $scope.addPhoto = function(){
    photos.create();
  };
}]);
```

While this question is specifically about the error I showed above, a pointer towards the correct direction would be helpful.

**Edit:** Here is my `app.js`, with the Multer code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

app.use(multer({'dest': './uploads'}).single('photo'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use('/uploads', express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing a node module to accept multi-part form data. If you are using the default body-parser module with express to parse your form data it will fail for multipart/* form content such as file uploads.

One of the module you can use to solve this is [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer). You can try as below:

```js
var express = require('express'),
  multer = require('multer'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  app = express();

app.use(multer({
  'dest': './uploads'
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

In your `<form>` tag inside Angular.js template, add an attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. and you are good to go.

Multer will parse your form for files and add it to request.files object as well as upload it to the specified destination directory with a unique file name.This file name can be accessed from request.file..name

A good tutorial can be found [here](http://joelennon.com/file-uploads-with-express-4-0/)

Comment: I am actually using Multer too, the problem is I get `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` at the following line: `var filename = req.files.name;`

Comment: When making post request add header for  `{'Content-Type': undefined}` and your browser will set it to multipart/form-data along with appropriate boundary. Also, Can you check if your request is sent correctly in the browser network console?

Comment: Did you mean to add the `Content-Type` header in the `o.create()` function under `Authorization` header?

Comment: Yes. `headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer '+auth.getToken(),'Content-Type': undefined }`

Comment: Is the selected file out of the scope of the code? I doubt it, but could that be the reason here?